# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views using Rxjava

Tags: android, android-layout, rx-java2

My problem is a got an error when I click quickly multiple time on  `bottomNavigationView` I got this error:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I handle `bottomNavigationView` clicks by using `Rxbinding`.
`model.getNews()` retrun a `Single<>` observable.

My code for handling `bottomNavigationView` clicks is:

```
    private Disposable loadNews(int categoryNumber) {

    return model.getNews(1, categoryNumber, OrderBy.DESC)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doFinally(() -> view.showLoading(false))
            .doOnSubscribe(__ -> view.showLoading(true) )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .retry()
            .map(NewsResponse::newsDetails)
            .subscribe(newsDetails -> view.setUpRecyclerView(newsDetails),
                    throwable -> ToastUtils.showShort("Error " + throwable.getMessage()
                            + "Caused by " + throwable.getCause()));

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to add another observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) lower in the stream, like so:

```
private Disposable loadNews(int categoryNumber) {

    return model.getNews(1, categoryNumber, OrderBy.DESC)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doFinally(() -> view.showLoading(false))
            .doOnSubscribe(__ -> view.showLoading(true) )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .retry()
            .map(NewsResponse::newsDetails)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) <-- HERE!
            .subscribe(newsDetails -> view.setUpRecyclerView(newsDetails),
                    throwable -> ToastUtils.showShort("Error " + throwable.getMessage()
                            + "Caused by " + throwable.getCause()));

}
```

Comment: it works thanks also `doAfterterminate` instead of `doFinally` works

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a direct fix for *why* your code attempts to access the views from a non-main thread, but I believe a simple band-aid fix would be simply debouncing clicks on the bottomNavigationView.

Code for that would look something like this (from memory, so please let me know if this doesn't work):

```
RxBinding.clicks(bottomNavigationView)
    .debounce(
        300 /* Time to debounce according to TimeUnit specified below */,
        TimeUnit.MILLIS
    )
    // .... continue with the rest of your Rx chain
```

Comment: It doesn't work actually it converts the flow to `RxComputing pool thread`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. You tried this code and it doesn't work?